# Jquery: Read Table Row and add effect to row on condition

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

Am adding dynamic data to Table , from AJAX call , I want to read the row which contain "BLOCK" string in it , if it is there add RED color to it ?

How can I achieve this.......?
Below is my current code

```
                  success: function(xml) {
                  var block_count;
                  var xmlDOM = $(xml);
                  block_count = $(xml).find('item').length;
                  xmlDOM.find("item").slice(position,position+page_size).each(function()       {
                            var $this=$(this);
                            var $user=$this.find("user").text();
                            var $tag=$this.find("tag").text();
                            var $action=$this.find("action").text();
                            var $time=$this.find("time").text();
            $("#datatable").append("<tbody><tr class='datarow'><td>"+$time+"</td> <td>"+$user+"</td><td>"+$url+"</td><td>"+$action+"</td></tr><tbody>");
                    });


         <table id='datatable' width="100%" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" style="line-height: .9em;">
                    <thead>
                            <tr id='tableheader'>
                                    <th>Time</th><th>User</th><th>tag</th><th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                    </thead>
         </table>
```

EDIT :How can I add red color if that row contain BLOCK string in that ....?

The table looks like this image[image]

Thank you

Comment: Where do you want to look for "BLOCK"?

Comment: after data get appended in table, The BLOCK string come on action column

Answer (score 0):

```
function change() {
$("#datatable tr.datarow:contains('BLOCK')").css({ "background":"red" });
}
```

You just have to trigger or execute the change function whenever you want or want it to change on event.

[Fiddle as Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf5n6/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$("#datatable").append("<tbody><tr class='datarow'><td>"+$time+"</td> <td>"+$user+"</td><td>"+$url+"</td><td>"+$action+"</td></tr><tbody>");
```

with:

```
$color = /BLOCK/.test($action) ? 'red' : '';
$("#datatable").append("<tbody><tr class='datarow "+$color+"'><td>"+$time+"</td> <td>"+$user+"</td><td>"+$url+"</td><td>"+$action+"</td></tr><tbody>");
```

Then add CSS:

```
.datarow.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: $color = /BLOCK/.test($action) ? 'red' : ''; , here its 'test' or 'text' ?

Comment: It's `test`, to test whether the string matches the regular expression.

Comment: its not coming :( I just added that CSS role in my main.css file .is that ok ?

Comment: Before Appending to table , is it possible to read XML data and check for that condition ?If yes Add RED color to it and append  ......?

Comment: See my change to the CSS. If you have a background-color already specified for `datarow`, this more specific setting will take precedence.

Comment: No change... Am getting 'red' when I write that color var to console , But color is not getting ADD

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23565/discussion-between-barmar-and-pervez)

Comment: I waited 15 minutes for you to click on the chat link, now I'm busy with other things. You're on your own.

Comment: Sorry For that Barmar :( Thank you so much for your time and response :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it,

It May help other,

```
  $color = /BLOCK/.test($action) ? 'red' : '';
  $("#datatable").append("<tbody><tr class='datarow'"+ $color +" ><td>"+$time+"</td> <td>"+$user+"</td><td>"+$url+"</td><td>"+$action+"</td></tr><tbody>");
  if ($color == "red"){
       $("tr.datarow:contains('BLOCK')").css('color','red');
   }
```

Thank you Guys